# Question about congruence modulo notation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am a bit confused about the semantics (or maybe it would be better to call it semiotics) of the congruence modulo. When we are presented with an expression of the form $$ a \equiv b\ (\textrm{mod}\ n)$$ this latter should be equivalent to the expression $$\exists\ c \in \mathbb{Z}\ : a - b = c\times n\ $$ Is it or is it not, and if not, why? If yes, can I use the equivalence in a formal proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent. Usually the former is defined as shorthand for the latter. As such in proofs you may cite this fact.

Comment: Wonderful, cheers for the quick answer!

Comment: Addendum: I will accept it when the 11 mins have passed.

Comment: I meant what you meant with the existence operator. I just forgot to add it. I am editing it now.

Comment: Ah, okay. I just thought I should be thorough.

Comment: Don't worry, I am very grateful that you pointed it out, tidiness is quite important in proofs.